# get запрос проблема с кодом страницы

Tags: get

При запросе через GET запрос странички google, не скачивается должным образом. То есть, если открываю исходный код, там есть ссылки которые я хочу спарсить, а когда делаю это программно через среду Delphi 7, компонент Synapse или Indy нет разницы, то получаю не тот результат, то есть какой-то другой код, и там нет тех ссылок, которые мне нужны.

Код :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var stroka: string;
begin
  stroka := 'https://www.google.ru/?gfe_rd=cr&#q=button&start=20';
  HttpGetText(stroka, mmo1.Lines);
end;
//нет ссылок в коде которые надо спарсить, но в исходном коде они есть
```

Comment: Есть сильное подозрение что исходная ссылка подгружает страницу с java-скриптом, который уже сам потом подгружает результаты поиска. Т.к. в httpsend идёт просто загрузка страницы по адресу, то Вы и получаете эту исходную страницу без результатов (ссылок). Простого решения я тут не вижу, если только не найти у гугла какого-нибудь API, который бы выдавал результаты поиска в чистом html.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы передаете не все HTTP-заголовки, по сравнению с вашим браузером, сервер анализирует их и в результате дает более подходящий ответ (как вариант, ответ не для русскоязычного пользователя, а для англоязычного).

Откройте консоль браузера на странице Network и посмотрите, что он отправляет на сервер. Уделите особое внимание работе со следующими HTTP-заголовками: `Set-Cookie`, `Accept-Language`, `Content-Type`, `User-Agent`.

Answer (score 1):

Это способ Гугла обойти роботов-парсеров. Они всегда будут бороться с этим.